# function not found after mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jhipster

Hi to all react geniuses. I am a newbie and I am trying to achieve a very simple thing here. 
Below is the code, which tries to call a function `sentTheAlert()` on button click. However, I get error in my console.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface IFancyAlerterProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{}> {}

export class FancyAlerter extends React.Component<IFancyAlerterProps> {
  handleSubmit= () => {
    this.props.sendTheAlert('hello');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Today Fancy Alert is {this.props.fancyInfo}</h1>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          See my Alert
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const SEND_MESSAGE = 'SEND_MESSAGE';

interface SendAlertType {
  type: typeof SEND_MESSAGE;
  payload: string;
}

function sendTheAlert(newMessage: string): SendAlertType {
  return {
    type: SEND_MESSAGE,
    payload: newMessage,
  };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = { sendTheAlert };

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { fancyInfo: 'Fancy this:' + state.currentFunnyString };
}

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FancyAlerter);
```

Note: If this information helps, I create a jhispter application with react UI. And tried to add a new component (FancyAlerter). All the old components are able to get my function however, the new component is unable to get this function or any other function.

So, I just don't understand the mechanics I believe. Any help would be really appreciated.

---

UPDATE: In the above code, the props contains methods from RouteComponentProps but not from the other two types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking into the issue. I figured it out. Of course all your answers helped me eliminate the possible causes.

Seems like how a component is imported makes a lot of difference i the react router file where all the routes were defined.

Supposedly below is my route

```
<ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/fancy" component={FancyAlerter} />
```

And the way you import this component is

```
import  FancyAlerter  from './modules/fancyalert/fancyalert';
```

Instead of

```
import  { FancyAlerter }  from './modules/fancyalert/fancyalert';
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like problem about using object for mapDispatchToProps. When you use mapDispatchToProps as an Object you should provide action creator, not void function :

```
const SEND_MESSAGE = 'SEND_MESSAGE'

interface SendAlertType {
  type: typeof SEND_MESSAGE
  payload: String
}

function sendTheAlert(newMessage: String): SendAlertType {
  return {
    type: SEND_MESSAGE,
    payload: newMessage
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { sendTheAlert };
```

Later on you can fire an alert on middleware (saga, thunk, etc.).

Check for the usage : https://daveceddia.com/redux-mapdispatchtoprops-object-form/

Test your code : https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-lake-h3rxr?file=/src/CounterMapDispatchObj.js

Comment: I guess your answer is right for majority of the cases, however I am not able to get mine working.. I am using TypeScript.

When I debug, I see the function is present in  mapDispatchToProps. However, it is not passed to the props object of my class.

Comment: @dharam You can update your question with the code that's not working for you. The answer given is correct pretty much covered what you did wrong in your original question.

Comment: @HMR thanks for taking interest. I updated the code according to Kerem's comment. I am still getting a undefined for this.props.sendTheAlert in handleSumbit method. 

If this helps, the code is written in a tsx file

Comment: @dharam i didnt test the code, it might have typos and bugs. i have just updated the code with removing undefined interface.

Comment: @Kerematam thats fine! i plugged in the missing pieces.. I suspect there is something wrong with my component. I also read the link you gave and thats why I said that your answer is right for majority of the cases, surprisingly other existing components are able to bind these actions. The component I wrote is not.. :)

Comment: @Kerematam, thanks for looking into this, I figured out the solution. Your answered helped me realize that there was nothing wrong with the component, but the way it was imported in the router.  I added the answer below for people who face this issue.